# Avoiding nested loops in a TicTacToe algorithm JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance, tic-tac-toe

I wrote a quick algorithm that detects a win in a TicTacToe Game.

fn `game()` loops through a simulated `ticTacToe` board, finds all the index's of a given value, then loops through all the possible winning combos, finds any index's where the actual value is equal to the index's from the first loop, (I know :/) then replaces the value with the value passed into the function (either x or o).

Then, a subsequent function is run that checks if every value inside any of the nested arrays inside the `possibleWinCombos` are all equal to each other. If true, a winner is found.

```
const possibleWinCombos = [
  [0, 1, 2], //================ //
  [3, 4, 5],  //== Horizontal == //
  [6, 7, 8],  //=================//

  [0, 3, 6],  //================ //
  [1, 4, 7],  //== Vertical == //
  [2, 5, 8],  //=================//
  
  [0, 4, 8],  //=================//
  [2, 4, 6],  //== Diagonal == //
]

const ticTacToe = [
  'x', 'o', null,
  null, 'x', null,
  'o', null, 'x',
]

const game = (value) => {
  ticTacToe.forEach((cell, idxOfCell) => {
    if(cell === value){
      for (winCombo of possibleWinCombos){
        let idxToReplace = winCombo.indexOf(idxOfCell) 
        winCombo.splice(idxToReplace, 1, value)
      }     
    }
  })
  
  checkForWinner(value) ? 
    console.log(`${value}'s win`) : console.log('game still going')
}

const checkForWinner = (value) => {
  return possibleWinCombos.some((winCombo) => {
    return winCombo.every((winComboValue) => winComboValue === value);
  })  
}

game('x') // x's win
game('o') // game still going
```

It's only two functions so it's not very code heavy but I feel like `game()` wouldn't score very high on the performance rankings due to the nested looping. Any recommendations on some improvements would be great.

https://replit.com/@uwitdat/DrabNoteworthyLogin#script.js

Comment: Why do you suspect the nested looping to be an issue here? In reality, you'll be checking the same amount of cells regardless of how you loop, right. So why would a different loop make a performance difference? What I suspect has happened here is that you're you've heard something about the multiplicative growth that can happen from nested loops and have therefore assumed that all nested loops must be avoided. Growth really only matters when the amount of interations significantly increases. For a set 3x3 board, that is not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should either end your statements with semicolons consistently, or not at all.  I recommend using semicolons consistently.

When writing `for (winCombo of possibleWinCombos)`, you didn't declare `winCombo`, so it's a global variable.

The biggest problem with your code is that it **trashes the contents of `possibleWinCombos`**, such that after execution, it has this value:

```
possibleWinCombos = [
  ["x", "o", "o"],
  [  3, "x", "o"],
  ["o",   7, "o"],
  ["x",   3, "o"],
  ["o", "x", "o"],
  [  2,   5, "o"],
  ["x", "x", "o"],
  [  2, "x", "o"]
]
```

… even though it was ostensibly `const`.  That means that if you ever run a rematch, your code won't work correctly unless you reinitialize `possibleWinCombos`.  If you're writing code in a functional style, you should aim for your functions to have no side-effects.

You don't really have to worry about performance or scalability, since the board will always be no bigger than 3×3.  That said, you should be aware that your algorithm calls **`.indexOf()`, which involves a hidden loop** to scan its array.

I recommend writing an `isWinner(board, player)` function.  The **two parameters** make it clear what the inputs are.  The name of the function makes it clear that it returns a boolean.  By defining it using an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), we can make it so that `possibleWinCombos` is available only to the code within `isWinner()`, which avoids polluting the global namespace.

```js
const isWinner = (() => {
  const possibleWinCombos = [
    [0, 1, 2],  //================//
    [3, 4, 5],  //== Horizontal ==//
    [6, 7, 8],  //================//

    [0, 3, 6],  //================//
    [1, 4, 7],  //=== Vertical ===//
    [2, 5, 8],  //================//
  
    [0, 4, 8],  //================//
    [2, 4, 6],  //=== Diagonal ===//
  ];

  return (board, player) => {
    return possibleWinCombos.some((winCombo) => {
      return winCombo.every((i) => board[i] === player);
    });
  };
})();


const ticTacToe = [
  'x', 'o', null,
  null, 'x', null,
  'o', null, 'x',
];

if (isWinner(ticTacToe, 'x')) console.log('x won');
if (isWinner(ticTacToe, 'o')) console.log('o won');
```

Comment: This is quite nice!!!